# How to apply global styling to html, body with SCSS without using @import

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, react-scripts

SASS advise you not to use @import as it will be deprecated in the future, but how does one apply global styling through SCSS then?

Answer (score 0):

Try `@use`

The new @use is similar to @import. but has some notable differences.

Comment: You are right about that, but I think I found the problem. react-scripts in start / build within package.json compiles scss if you have node-sass installed. react-scripts which comes from create-react-app auto compiles scss into css on runtime and buildtime, but it does not seem @use is supported... even after 2 years. Scratched my skull to land on this, but the solution I found was to use sass --watch style.scss style.css and just import style.css normally.